# Can I combine those two functions into one

Tags: jquery

Can I combine those two jQuery functions into one? They got same selector and it looks like can be  shortened down or simplified.I just start to learn jquery so don't know how to do it.Can someone help? Thanks

```js
  $(function(){
   $(".button").click(function(){
     var box=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
  
     return false;
});
   $(".button").on('click',function(){
  var box=$(this).attr('data-box');
   $('#'+box).toggle();
    
   });
 });
```

```css
.panel{ width: 80px;height: 25px; background: tan; display: inline-block;position:absolute;
 }
.panel p{ margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
 } 
.button{ width: 30px;height: 30px; background: pink; display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
#box1 {top:50px;left:20px; display: none;}
#box2 {top:50px;left:120px;display: none;}
#box3 {top:50px;left:220px;display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button" data-box="box1" >A
</div>
<div class="button" data-box="box2"> B
</div>
<div class="button" data-box="box3"> C
</div>
<div id="nav">
  <div id="box1" class="panel ">
  <p>content</p>
 </div>
 <div id="box2" class="panel ">
  <p>content</p>
 </div>
 <div id="box3" class="panel">
  <p>content</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: first one does nothing, what's it expected to do?

Comment: @ charlietfl  first one is for able to make div clickable.

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't make sense. No idea what `make div clickable` means

Comment: Sorry , after I read Lajos Arpad's answer I understand I don't have to add first function. I thought div have no button function so needed one to make it run. -_-

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not.

```
  $(function(){
      $(".button").click(function(){
     var box=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 

     var box=$(this).attr('data-box');
      $('#'+box).toggle();

     return false;
   });
 });
```

Just make sure to move the `return false` to the end.

Comment: don't you think the `return false;` will skip the lower code section?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got this question right, but i guess your answer is ;

```
$(function(){
      $(".button").click(function(){
     var box=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 

var box1=$(this).attr('data-box');
      $('#'+box1).toggle();
     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
      $(".button").click(function() {
        var url = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

        var box = $(this).attr('data-box');
        $('#' + box).toggle();

        return false;
      });
);
```

I'm not sure what the first variable is supposed to do (it never gets used), but I left it there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any anchors in your html, therefore it seems to me that your first function is not needed, therefore the code I would suggest is:

```
$(function() {
    $(".button").on('click',function(){
        var box=$(this).attr('data-box');
        $('#'+box).toggle();

    });
});
```